# Error on calling procedure from oracle to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, oracle, stored-procedures, plsqldeveloper

Hi i am creating a application using stored procedure. I am not able to insert data into table.

**My table is:**

```
SQL> create table test (name varchar2(20), qualification varchar2(10), address v
archar2(100));

Table created.
```

**My stored procedure is**

```
SQL> create or replace procedure inserttest (
  2  p_name test.name%TYPE,
  3  p_qualification test.qualification%TYPE,
  4  p_address test.address%TYPE)
  5  IS
  6  BEGIN
  7  INSERT INTO test (name, qualification, address)
  8  VALUES (p_name, p_qualification, p_address);
  9  COMMIT;
 10  END;
 11  /

Procedure created.
```

**My C# Code is:**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=xe;Persist Security Info=True;Password=sesu;User ID=system");
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_name", OleDbType.VarChar ).Value = TextBox1.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_qualification", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_address", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox3.Text;
            cmd = new OleDbCommand ("inserttest", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close(); 

        }
```

**I am not able to insert data through C#. It shows:**

```
One or more errors occurred during processing of command.
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'INSERTTEST'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

What is the problem.? How to solve it.?

Answer (score 1):

I think `PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'INSERTTEST'` because of you have `varchar2(20)` in table .In codebehind you have mentioned `OleDbType.VarChar`.And also check your stored procedure datatype and use correct datatype

In stored peoedure try like this

```
   create or replace procedure inserttest (
   p_name varchar2(20),
   p_qualification varchar2(20),
   p_address varchar2(20))
IS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO test (name, qualification, address)
VALUES (p_name, p_qualification, p_address);
COMMIT;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to define static types for your parameters in your stored procedure:

```sql
create or replace procedure inserttest (
    p_name          in varchar2,
    p_qualification in varchar2,
    p_address       in varchar2
)
IS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO test (name, qualification, address)
    VALUES (p_name, p_qualification, p_address);
    COMMIT;
END;
```